# How to extract variable from string in Bash using Regex?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

The string look like

```
str1= "the value of var1=test, the value of var2=testing, the final value of var3=testing1"
```

Upto now I split the string by IFS=','

```
IFS="," read -r -a final <<< "$str1"
```

Then assigning values to variables

```
var1="${final[0]#"var1="}"
```

How to assign the variable values in shortest way using regex?

Expected Output

```
var1=test
var2=testing
var3=testing1
```

Comment: I suggesto to remove space after `str1=`.

Comment: "Using regex" -- so you wouldn't accept a perfectly functional answer if it was implemented any other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
str1="the value of var1=test, the value of var2=testing, the final value of var3=testing1"
re='(^|[[:space:]])([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*)=([^, ]+)([, ]|$)(.*)'

remaining=$str1
while [[ $remaining =~ $re ]]; do
  varname=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  value=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
  remaining=${BASH_REMATCH[5]}
  printf -v "$varname" %s "$value"
done

# show current values to demonstrate that variables were really assigned
declare -p var1 var2 var3
```

This works because `=~` stores each match group in your regex in a different position in the `BASH_REMATCH` variable, so we're able to pick out the groups with the names and values and perform an indirect assignment (`printf -v varname %s "$value"` stores `value` in `varname`).

The regex has a fair bit going on, so let's break it down piece-by-piece:

- `(^|[[:space:]])` ensures that we only match content at the beginning of the string or preceded by a space.
- `([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*)=([^, ]+)` matches only assignments where the left-hand side is a valid variable name (a letter, optionally followed by characters that can be either letters or numbers). Because your sample data has commas following values, we know a comma can't be allowed *in* a value, so we disallow both commas and spaces from being considered part of a value.
- `([, ]|$)` allows a variable to terminate either with a comma or space following, or at the end of input.
- `(.*)'` matches any remaining content we haven't yet processed, so that content can be run against the regex on the time cycle through the loop.

Comment: Works on  bash described but on't work with Jenkins sh

Comment: @profimedica sh doesn't have any built-in regex support, so that's expected. This _is_ a question tagged `bash`.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually one where `grep` with `-E` extended regex matching can help, e.g.

```
grep -E -o 'var[0-9]*[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*[^,[:blank:]]+' <<< $str
```

Results in:

```
var1=test
var2=testing
var3=testing1
```

The `[[:blank:]]*` on either side of the `'='` just allows for spaces on either side, if present. If there is never a chance of that, you can shorten it to `grep -E -o 'var[0-9]*=[^,[:blank:]]+'`.

**Edit Per-Comment**

To store it in `var1`, simply:

```
var1=$(grep -E -o 'var[0-9]*[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*[^,[:blank:]]+' <<< $str)
```

(or better, store each combination in an array, or create an associative array from the variable names and values themselves) For example, to store all of the `var=val`  combinations in an associative array you could do:

```
str="the value of var1=test, the value of var2=testing, the final value of var3=testing1"
declare -A array
while read -r line; do 
    array[${line%=*}]=${line#*=}
done < <(grep -E -o 'var[0-9]*[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*[^,[:blank:]]+' <<< $str)
for i in ${!array[@]}; do
    echo "$i => ${array[$i]}"
done
```

**Example Output**

```
var1 => test
var3 => testing1
var2 => testing
```

Comment: This command just print the variable with corresponding value, and not storing the values in variable name.